# Queries regarding Shutdown hook

Tags: java, eclipse, shutdown-hook

1. If i have gotten it correctly each java process is associated with a separate instance of JVM and each instance of JVM is provided with a Heap memory by the OS which is also recollected by the OS on JVM termination. `So on termination even if there were some memory leaks all the memory will be reclaimed by the OS(Please correct if I have mistaken)`.
2. In case point number 1 is true why do we have to use shutdown hooks. After googling everything mainly suggests to free all the resources and graceful shutdown. `Even if it does not gracefully shutdown all the memory and resources would be freed?`
3. I wrote a simple shutdown hook. In my main thread I am running an infinite loop and then terminating the process using terminate button in `Eclipse`. But the shutdown hook thread is not running. 
   Does terminating process in eclipse call `Runtime.getRuntime().halt(status)` because AFAIK that terminated JVM abruptly and not execute shutdown hook?
4. Lastly if I have my main code something like below -

   ```
   public static void main(String args[]){
   Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(new ShutDownHook()));
   System.out.println("Shutdown hook registered");
   System.out.println("Before calling exit");
   System.exit(0);
   System.out.println("After exit");       
   }
   ```

   why is `After exit` not printed? When shutdown hook is in execution main thread must continue further execution and print `After exit`?

Answer (score 4):

**1)** You are correct.

**2)** The Java process' memory will be reclaimed, but you might want to do other cleanup, like delete some temp files.

**3)** Let's go to the javadoc of `Runtime#addShutdownHook(Thread)`

> The Java virtual machine shuts down in response to two kinds of
>   events:
>
> - The program exits normally, when the last non-daemon thread exits or
>     when the exit (equivalently, System.exit) method is invoked, or
> - The virtual machine is terminated in response to a user interrupt,
>     such as typing ^C, or a system-wide event, such as user logoff or
>     system shutdown.

You would have to look into Eclipse's source code, but it would seem like Eclipse terminates the process rather than sending a `System.exit(..)` or a sending a user interrupt. This probably goes over the JVM which therefore doesn't execute the shutdown hooks.

**4)** The shutdown hooks you add with `Runtime#addShutdownHook(Thread)` are added to a `static` `IdentityHashMap` in the `ApplicationShutdownHooks`. This class registers its own shutdown hook with the `Shutdown` class in a `static` initializer block shown below

```
static {
    try {
        Shutdown.add(1 /* shutdown hook invocation order */,
            false /* not registered if shutdown in progress */,
            new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    runHooks();
                }
            }
        );
        hooks = new IdentityHashMap<>();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        // application shutdown hooks cannot be added if
        // shutdown is in progress.
        hooks = null;
    }
}
```

The `runHooks()` method is

```
static void runHooks() {
    Collection<Thread> threads;
    synchronized(ApplicationShutdownHooks.class) {
        threads = hooks.keySet();
        hooks = null;
    }

    for (Thread hook : threads) {
        hook.start();
    }
    for (Thread hook : threads) {
        try {
            hook.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException x) { }
    }
}
```

So the current thread joins all the other ones.

When

```
System.exit(0);
```

gets called, somewhere down the line `Shutdown.sequence()` gets called which invokes `Shutdown.hooks()` implemented as

```
private static void runHooks() {
    for (int i=0; i < MAX_SYSTEM_HOOKS; i++) {
        try {
            Runnable hook;
            synchronized (lock) {
                // acquire the lock to make sure the hook registered during
                // shutdown is visible here.
                currentRunningHook = i;
                hook = hooks[i];
            }
            if (hook != null) hook.run();
        } catch(Throwable t) {
            if (t instanceof ThreadDeath) {
                ThreadDeath td = (ThreadDeath)t;
                throw td;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

One of the `Runnable` objects in `hooks` is what I described above. It doesn't spawn a new `Thread`, it does it concurrently with `run()`.

Once `Shutdown.sequence()` is done, the system really exits, so the final `System.out.println()` doesn't execute.